# How to create multi output stream from single input stream with Spring Cloud Kafka stream binder?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying  to create multi output streams(depend on different time window) from single input stream.

```
interface AnalyticsBinding {
        String PAGE_VIEWS_IN = "pvin";
        String PAGE_VIEWS _COUNTS_OUT_Last_5_Minutes = "pvcout_last_5_minutes";
        String PAGE_VIEWS _COUNTS_OUT_Last_30_Minutes = "pvcout_last_30_minutes";
        @Input(PAGE_VIEWS_IN)
        KStream<String, PageViewEvent> pageViewsIn();
        @Output(PAGE_VIEWS_COUNTS_OUT_Last_5_Minutes)
        KStream<String,Long> pageViewsCountOutLast5Minutes();
        @Output(PAGE_VIEWS_COUNTS_OUT_Last_30_Minutes)
        KStream<String,Long> pageViewsCountOutLast30Minutes();
    }

  @StreamListener
  @SendTo({ AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEWS_COUNTS_OUT_Last_5_Minutes })
    public KStream<String, Long> processPageViewEventForLast5Mintues(
            @Input(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEWS_IN)KStream<String, PageViewEvent> stream) {
                  // aggregate by Duration.ofMinutes(5)
    }


  @StreamListener
  @SendTo({ AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEWS_COUNTS_OUT_Last_30_Minutes })
    public KStream<String, Long> processPageViewEventForLast30Mintues(
            @Input(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEWS_IN)KStream<String, PageViewEvent> stream) {
                  // aggregate by Duration.ofMinutes(30)
}
```

When I start the application just one stream task would work, Is there a way to get both  **processPageViewEventForLast5Mintues** and **processPageViewEventForLast30Mintues** work simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same input binding in both processors and that's why you are seeing only one as working. Add another input binding in the binding interface and set it's destination to the same topic. Also, change one of the `StreamListener` methods to use this new binding name.

With that said, if you are using the latest versions of Spring Cloud Stream, you should consider migrating to a functional model. For e.g. the following should work.

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, PageViewEvent>, KStream<String, Long>> processPageViewEventForLast5Mintues() {
...
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, PageViewEvent>, KStream<String, Long>> processPageViewEventForLast30Mintues() {
...
}
```

The binder automatically creates two distinct input bindings in this case.
You can set destinations on those bindings.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processPageViewEventForLast5Mintues-in-0.destination=<your Kafka topic>
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processPageViewEventForLast30Mintues-in-0.destination=<your Kafka topic>
```